# What is good practice to accessing package private variables?

Tags: java, accessor, package-private

What is good practice to access my package-private variables from other classes in this same package?

1. Package-private accessor

   ```
   String getColor() {
       return color;
   }
   ```
2. Just accessing as field from object.

   ```
   String color = instanceOfClass.color;
   ```

In my opinion:

1. Package-private method for accessing package-private field. A lot of unnecessary code, but in my opinion provides clarity with a lot of fields (and properly named accessor methods)
2. We don't need accessors and mutators for package-private variables in package, so maybe I shouldn't create them?

Which practice is better, consistent with the programming convention?

EDIT: Thank you for fast answers! :)

Comment: The fact that they're package private makes no difference. Just do the same as you would otherwise. If things are declared final and are immutable, I don't really see how a getter method serves any purpose. I know people who would disagree.

Comment: I disagree. Getter methods are more flexible, handle ancillary logic, guard clients against change, and hide the implementation even within packages. I would suggest making the variable `private` and the accessor package-private.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having accessors/mutators is usually handy even if it is some more code:

- If you later introduce some logic when accessing/setting the variable, you can do it just in one place without the need to affect all the classes using the variable - you can easily add features as additional logging, lazy loading, security, validation, ...
- You can later change the underlying representation of the field (eg return subtype in some cases)
- You can later introduce lifecycle management of the returned object - eg. Return pooled/cached/singleton/.. object
- You can later decide to return Proxy/decorated object instead without affecting callers

Generally, it is a good idea as it gives you more flexibility, preserves encapsulation and reduces coupling between objects.

Comment: Looks like best answer for me, connected with https://stackoverflow.com/a/44661193/7687125 answer. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 3):

Accessors and mutators have more to do with abstraction than they do with encapsulation. You want to be able to control *how* that field is set, rather than letting anyone put some random value in there. For example, you might have a value that should never be null, so..

```
void setField(Field field) {
    if(field != null) {
        this.field = field;
    }
}
```

And then you would declare your `field` variable as `private`. If you allow anyone to write anything into it, then this logic would need to be moved to everywhere that sets it, which will cause code duplication.

Comment: You really don't care *how* the field is set, as you say. You care about *what it's set to*. You don't want an object that can encapsulate an invalid state. The key thing is that it's about control

Answer (score 0):

Use accessors only when necessary. Other than that, it is best to only allow package private variables to be accessed inside of that package. For example, if the variable is some value used in a calculation, do what you need with it **inside the package** using a public method call from another package, and then pass it to your other package.

Comment: "it is best to only allow package private variables to be accessed inside of that package" Isn't that actually the very definition of package-private? How would classes outside the package access package-private members?

Comment: @Lew Bloch via public method calls. The variable is private for a reason. Using some type of setter or accessor is not reasonable if it is private

Comment: That's accessing public methods. My question is how could it access _package-private_ members, speaking to your advice that "it is best to only allow package private [_sic_] variables to be accessed inside of that package". I wasn't aware that there was any choice in the matter.

Comment: @Lew Bloch ahh yes very true. My take on the question was how (public methods) to access those package private variables.

Answer (score 0):

Best practice is to use Getters and Setters.

This allows additional functionality (like validation) to be added more easily later and prevents you from giving the privilage of directly accessing these variables from other class.

```
private String color = InstanceOfClass.color;

String getColor(){
    if(background == White)
        return Black;

    else
        return White;

    }
```

You can have a good information about them here:
[Getter Setter: To Use or Not to Use](https://dzone.com/articles/getter-setter-use-or-not-use-0)